# iPhone simulator not scrolling on windows (not Windows™, a window brought up on a website)

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website that's optimized for mobile devices that can also be used on a desktop. In order to test the functionality of it without setting up a server, I'm using the iPhone simulator that comes with XCode. The website's purpose is to give a manager for the business a way of approving or rejecting potential offers the marketers have in mind to give to customers when they are away from their desk. When you get to the Approve/Reject page, you can click either the Approve or Reject button. Each button, once pressed will bring up a window (not a separate page) where the manager can add comments. On the iPhone simulator, whenever the window comes up, the iPhone will not let you scroll down at all on the window as, for some reason, the scroll function still seems to be connected to the main page, not the window that just came up. The problem only occurs on the iPhone part of the simulator, but not on the iPad part. I've been beaten by this problem for several days and I can't find anything on the internet that gives suggestions. Does anybody have any idea on what I should do with the coding, or if it's just what happens when you run the server locally on the simulator? Any help will be appreciated, as I've exhausted all I can think of.

Note: I'm using Ruby-on-Rails and the window that is popping up us a Bootstrap modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Modal box on iPhone no scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067802/modal-box-on-iphone-no-scroll)

The modal becomes a static height on the screen and it should allow you to scroll all the way to the bottom of that window.
Change the height setting so that it fits.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, thank you supreme coding overlord. I am eternally grateful and the company thanks you for your help and contribution to the project.