# Bootstrap modal issue on Safari/iOS/iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

Bootstrap modal fade is working perfectly on Chrome/Internet Explorer, but it doesn't work on the iPhone/Safari. Does someone a solution for this issue?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="notice" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="notice" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="https://random.hellyer.kiwi/files/2013/11/wiley-coyote-help.jpg" />
                | wait, I'm updating...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#notice').modal('show');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#notice').modal('hide');
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmbtfhaf/

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using for the modal and describe what doesn't work in safari?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem these days and figured out, that safari on iOS is working differently to other browsers with respect to one thing. The modal window is not shown on safari but on many other browsers, when there is a href="#" missing.

not working on Safari/iOS but other browsers:

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">Modal</a></li>
```

working on Safari/iOS and other browsers:

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">Modal</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I'm not creating a modal, but using a pre-made modal div, so I'm just calling the effect with a modal code.

Comment: @vinoli did you solve your issue? I'm having the same issue with a modal div called with jquery and this answer doesn't solve it because I don't have any href

Comment: @z3d0 Hi, did you solve your issue? I have your same issue and I can't solve it!

Comment: @Brian-Vanegas-Parra unfortunately I didn't solve it yet

Comment: U saved my  day!

Comment: to be clear, this works in the link to call the modal

Answer (score 9):

I found this answer that solved the problem for me. The problem is that iOs doesn't realize that the tag is clickable.

Create a CSS style as follows:

```
.clickable {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

In your modal code, add the clickable class:

```
<li><a data-toggle="modal" class="clickable" data-target="#modalDelete">Delete</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you, Pam, this worked for my problem with Bootstrap 4 tabs.

Answer (score 4):

If you make the 'a' tag an 'button' instead, it's working in both safari IOS and desktop browsers.

```
<li><button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">Modal</button></li>
```

Comment: This solution will sometimes raise warnings in HTML validators, so use at your own risk. For an alternative, look at Pam Nelligan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change `transition: all .3s ease;` to `transition: opacity .3s ease, transform .3s ease;` this fixed my issue.