# Bootstrap dropdown inside modal is hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a bootstrap modal that has a button inside. When the button is pressed a dropdown is opened. On chrome and Firefox the dropdown overlaps the modal border and works fine, but on safari the dropdown is hidden. It stays within the border of the modal and looks like it is behind the modal.
If some code is needed I will put some up but I'm sure somebody else has ran into this issue before.

Comment: Isn't it the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772684/bootstrap-modal-issue-on-safari-ios-iphone`? If you could put your code, it will be easy to debug.

Comment: That is not the same issue, i will post a screenshot of my issue and some code.