# Modal will not show on Safari

Tags: css

The modal shows on all browsers other than Safari...Help! It looks like it doesn't even try and display, all other browsers it pops up nicely

```
.simplemodal-container {
  height: auto !important;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s; }
  .simplemodal-container.dn-modal-scale {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1); }
    .simplemodal-container.dn-modal-scale .dn-modal-progress .dn-modal-icon .fa-check {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1); }
  .simplemodal-container.dn-modal-noanimation {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none; }
```

Here is the HTML as requested.

```
<div class="dn-snippet" id="dn-snippet-nautachoicemodal" ><div id="nauta-choice-modal" class="dn-modal-wrap">
  <div class="dn-modal dn-light-modal">
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" class="simplemodal-close">
        <span class="">X</span>
      </div>
    <div class="dn-modal-content">
      <h3 class="dn-modal-title">Cuban top-up.</h3>
      Nauta top-up is now available for Cuba.<br>Please select the product you would like to top-up.
    </div>
    <div class="dn-modal-footer">
      <button class="simplemodal-left-btn">Phone top-up</button>
      <button class="simplemodal-right-btn">Nauta top-up</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: possibly dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772684/bootstrap-modal-issue-on-safari-ios-iphone

Comment: What exactly is supposed to show? If I put this in a html file, it just displays the text, in the same way in Safari and other browsers. Also, which version of Safari are we talking about?