# JQuery does not open Bootstrap modal on mobile(iPhone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have a Javascript/JQuery function which is supposed to open a bootstrap modal after an AJAX request.

This works on PC using Chrome but unfortunately it doesn't work on iPhone(Chrome/Safari)

> **The button:**

```
<button type="button" id="GetEmployees" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="GetEmployees()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">&nbsp;</span>Toevoegen
</button>
```

> **The function:**

```
function GetEmployees() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: appPath + '/TimeRegistration/GetEmployees',
        data: {  },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                alert("Load");
                $("#dialog-project .modal-body").html(response);
                $("#dialog-project").modal("show");
                alert("open");
            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Onbekende fout opgetreden")
        }
    });
}
```

> **And here is the dialog itself:**

```
<div id="dialog-project" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="color: #333333;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 id="dialog-title" class="modal-title">Aanmaken nieuwe tijdregel</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For some reason on iPhone I get the alert "Load" but the modal isn't showing up and also the last alert is not showing up.

**edit2**: In order to make the buttons execute the JS at the first place I had to add:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var touchEvent = 'onclick' in window ? 'click' : 'touchstart';
    $('#GetEmployees').on('click touchstart', function () {
        GetEmployees();
    })
})
```

Comment: Does it works on firefox or edge on PC ?

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani Yes it works on Firefox as well on pc ;)

Comment: the thing with cursor:pointer; doesnt seem to be integrated correct, bootstrap should add cursor:pointer to the buttons, not?

Comment: which version of bootstrap you are using ?

Comment: @NarendraJadhav Bootstrap v3,  and johnSmith I think not. I can't imagine it being the problem as the JS functions are executed correctly, untill we call the modals.

Comment: If the v3.x modal examples on the bootstrap site work fine on the same iPhone, and your page works on other browsers, then maybe you could try debugging via something like Vorlon? Or a Mac + Safari if you have one of those.

Comment: @Falcon, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28792552/177416

Comment: Try this. http://touchpunch.furf.com/. Its a "hack" for jQuery UI to encapsulate or unify all the similar events both from pc and mobile.

Comment: @Falcon hey did you solve it? What solution did you used? Share with the others..

Comment: but you're not using the variable `touchEvent` in your snippet?

Comment: You might also find this helpful. http://gravitydept.com/blog/js-click-event-bubbling-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

I am also faced a same issue. I was fixed by following code.

```
$( "#code" ).on('shown', function(){
    $('body').css('position','fixed');
});
```

In IOS browser position has issue and it take fixed position.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to css issue on ios dervices.

Just use cursor: pointer; in css. you can add class in it.
as like:-

```
.iosmodal{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetEmployees() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: appPath + '/TimeRegistration/GetEmployees',
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        if (response != null) {
            console.log("Load");
            $("#dialog-project .modal-body").html(response);
            $("#dialog-project").modal("show");
            console.log("open");
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Error status: " + status);
        console.log("Error message: " + error);
        alert("An unknown error occurred. Please try again.");
    }
});
```

}

Here's an updated version of the function with some additional error handling using **console.log**:

By using console.log statements, you can inspect the browser's console to see any error messages or logs. This can provide more specific information about what might be going wrong on the iPhone device.

Remember to test your application on multiple devices and browsers to ensure cross-platform compatibility. If you encounter specific error messages or behaviors, you can provide more details for further assistance.