# I created bootstrap modal in website. but i can't open the modal pop-up in safari browser?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created a bootstrap-4 modal pop-up in my website. isn't working for safari browser. except all browsers are working so how can I solve this problem

Comment: Add code please. Working is good in safari https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/P2qy1

Comment: I just copied from bootstrap. the same code only I paste. But it's not working for the safari browser. another all browsers I can open.

Comment: Wath you use in plugins, add please?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="content/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

Comment: Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28772684/bootstrap-modal-issue-on-safari-ios-iphone

Comment: Also added hover effects for the attributes that one also not showing in the safari browser...

Comment: I checked all browser and no see the problem and of course in Safari, working good http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/v4-alpha/components/modal/, enable JavaScript in your browser Safari - https://www.lifewire.com/disable-javascript-in-safari-4103708